# .htaccess 301 redirect conflicting with rewriterule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect the URL but its conflicting with the rewrite-rule, I am using this redirection Rule

```
Redirect 301 /antique-vintage-rugs/170-antique-oriental-rugs-carpets https://example.com/antique-vintage-rugs/170-antique-rugs
```

it took me to this link
    https://example.com/antique-vintage-rugs/170-antique-rugs?action=clear&template=170-antique-oriental-rugs-carpets    instead of this
    https://example.com/antique-vintage-rugs/170-antique-rugs

My Rewrite URL is this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^antique-vintage-rugs/(.+) results.php?action=clear&template=$1 [NC]
```

Is there any way I can get the desired output redirect link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to only be using mod_rewrite here instead of mixing it with mod_alias (where the `Redirect` directive belongs). When you mix the two, both end up processing the same request.

So instead of `Redirect`,  use:

```
RewriteRule ^antique-vintage-rugs/170-antique-oriental-rugs-carpets https://example.com/antique-vintage-rugs/170-antique-rugs [L,R=301]
```

but make sure it's **before** your other rules.

Answer (score 0):

I had a somewhat similar problem. I was trying to add redirects from cpanel while I already had some rewrite rules written in my .htaccess file. The error I got was "No maching  tag for "
What I ultimately did was that kept a copy of my existing rules and cleaned the .htaccess. Then went and added all the redirects that I needed from cpanel, and then at the end put back my own rewrite rules in the end of the file. That worked for me